# Simple scala project using framework springscala (not scala instead of java project)

Tags: spring, scala

Is spring scala projects are available ?.

**Not  Scala instead of Java** projects . Spring only for scala language.

I really search for that but available examples are scala instead of java.

if you have any idea about this please share with me..

with regards   Prasanth

Comment: Hi, if you could share some link to the examples you found, it would be easier to better understand your needs. Thanks

Comment: @pagoda_5b  sorry the question not understanding .. at that time but i just update it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you look on github - there are lots here!

https://github.com/search?q=scala-spring&ref=cmdform

Some of them are outdated though.

Answer (score 5):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but if you are asking if there is an implementation of DI (Spring) written in pure Scala by the folks at SpringSource, there isn't.  If you are looking for a Scala wrapper around the existing Spring framework written in Java, you can find it [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-scala).

Using this framework lets you do neat things like:

```
class TransactionalExample extends TransactionManagement {
    val dataSoure: DataSource = ...
    val jdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource)
    val transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource)

    val result: String = transactional() {
        status => {
            jdbcTemplate.queryForObject[String]("SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = 1")
        }
    }
}
```

[Code taken from here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-scala/wiki/Using-Spring-Templates-in-Scala)

Comment: firstly  thanx.. for your answer but i want a simple scala project that uses pure springscala framework and not scala instead of java...

Comment: No worries...  Then you might want to check out a different DI framework instead of Spring.  One that I really like is called [Subcut](https://github.com/dickwall/subcut).